# WPF: How can I retrieve the Template that was created by a ContentTemplateSelector for a specific ContentPresenter?

Tags: wpf, contenttemplateselector

In my WPF app, I'm using several ContentPresenters with a special MarkupExtension that requires access to the ContentPresenter's ContentTemplate property.

The MarkupExtension works very well, except that I just found out that if a ContentPresetner uses a ContentTemplateSelector, it doesn't set its own ContentPresenter property: rather, both the ContentPresenter and the result of the ContentTemplateSelector get saved to a private variable of the ContentPresenter class, as can be seen here: [link to .Net source code for ContentPresenter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentPresenter.cs,d7b404c93b74c594,references).

I figured out that I can call ContentTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate() again and get the template, or keep a dictionary of selected templates inside the ContentTemplateSelector so that I can fetch the template that was geneatedfor each element, but is there a better way to do this?